# How do I rotate a JPEG image by 45° and save it back to disk in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, image-manipulation

How do I rotate a JPEG image by 45° and save it back to disk?

Comment: Out of curiousity, What does it mean to rotate an image 45%?  Is that 40.5° or perhaps 162° (360° being 100%)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write 45 degrees. I don't know why I always type % when I mean °.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no good image manipulation library for Haskell yet.

#### Better way

You can use `hsmagick` (bindings to libmagick) to manipulate images.

See [TomMD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413381/haskell-how-do-i-rotate-a-jpeg-image-by-45-and-save-it-back-to-disk/3416723#3416723) for an example.

#### Easy way

But if you want to do it from Haskell, this can do the trick (assuming that ImageMagick is available):

```
import System.Cmd (system)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
  (original:rotated:_) <- getArgs
  system $ "convert -rotate \"-45\" \"" ++ original ++ "\" \"" ++ rotated ++ "\""
```

Usage:

```
runghc rotate.hs original.jpg rotated45.jpg
```

#### Hard way

Or you can choose the hard way, and implement [rotation algorithm](http://www.google.it/search?hl=en&q=Alan+Paeth:+%22A+Fast+Algorithm+for+General+Raster+Rotation%22) yourself. To read and write almost all image formats in Haskell, you can use [Codec.Image.DevIL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Codec-Image-DevIL) library. If you do it, it would be kind of you to put this code on Hackage.

Answer (score 6):

The GD library lets you do this, but the Haskell bindings ( http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gd ) don't include the appropriate function at the moment. One also could either make a feature request to the maintainer, or simply patch it and send it upstream. The Graphics.GD.Internal module (not exported) in fact already has a commented out binding to the appropriate function ( http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gd/3000.5.0/doc/html/src/Graphics-GD-Internal.html ), so it should be very simple, I imagine, to finish the job (and I'm sure, the work will be appreciated).

Answer (score 5):

Look around on Hackage.  I know Tim started working on [bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsmagick) to libmagick, which wasn't enough to stop me from dropping down to generating script-fu for GIMP when I needed image manipulation, but it's enough for you if you're just doing simple things like rotation:

```
liftM (rotateImage 45) (readImage file) >>= writeImage file2
```

I see Cale also has an [ImLib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Imlib) that appears more feature complete:

```
loadImageImmediately file >>= contextSetImage >>
createRotatedImage 45 >>= contextSetImage >> saveImage file2
```

As I said, look around and let us know!

Comment: Weird. The ImLib binding for saveImage appears to be wrong/not filled in. :-(

Comment: sclv: That's what I thought at first but see the edit - ImLib is stateful (damn IO)

Comment: aha. contextsetimage! oy vey.